# What is this tool and what is it used for?

Tags: remodeling

Approx 6’ long rack with 4 fixtures on it. Rack had thumb screws allowing it to expand or contract. My father was a remodeling contractor but we never used this.  No model or brand marks of any kind.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe a homemade setup jig.  Does any of it move when turning the thumb screws?

Comment: Looks like something that helps adjust floor boards and the like, to get them looser or tighter to match the framing.

Comment: It's difficult to see detail in the dark image. My guess is a hinge mortising jig. but that pure speculation.

Comment: Hard to see, could it be for laminating wood strips? I had something similar but it was curved. I would take hard wood and steam it then clamp several pieces in the vices, when it dried in the curved shape I would add glue and re clamp until dry.

Comment: That picture is very small and hard to make out any detail in, please try again. preferably against a lighter background and better lit.

Comment: With the better picture, I think @mikes is right, and should answer.

Comment: Four fixtures?   We only see one.